# Do I really need lower-resolution images for older iOS devices?

Tags: ios, image, screen-resolution

I am developing an iphone application and i am using a background picture for my app. I know that before iphone 4 , the resolution of the screen was 480x320 and after 960x640. I read that i should use 2 images like : `MyImage.png` and `MyImage@2x.png` with the 2 different resolutions and the app will know which one to choose according to the phone. My question is very simple. If i just use the 960x480 , whats the difference? I am developing on an iphone 3gs and i am using this resolution and everything works perfect. So why have a small resolution for these phones?

Comment: Don't be lazy, for Android you need at least 4 different sizes of every image to be on the safe side ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference, in my opinion, is the following: the phone is going to resize the doubled-resolution to half the size, and this will lead to (1) the final image is not as smooth as if you would have exported it from a image application like Illustrator or Photoshop - at least from my own experience, when I export both resolutions, in non retina devices, the images don't look as good if I had exported the normal resolution. Also (2) the device will waste time/performance to make this conversion, although I don't know how much it is significant. And (3) finally, you may overload memory with no need, considering that the doubled sized images are bigger files, and you could use smaller files instead.

If you don't mind about this issues, you can go ahead. Try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, the high-resolution images will tax the memory much more. One full-screen image at 320✕480 is around 600K in memory, whereas the 640✕960 is almost 2.5M, four times as much. On the older devices the memory is much more scarce than on the new ones and you might run into problems later in the development cycle, when there are more resources in play.

Even if you are able to test the app on all older supported devices and you can guarantee that there are no immediate performance problems or visual glitches, the app will take more memory, forcing the OS to kill other apps more frequently (= worse overall user experience).

Answer (score 1):

if you use one version of image, (960x640) , there will be a memory overhead when the app run on non-retina. you dont need to display the high res in non-retina, only in retina display, making two versions of images .png and @2x.png will tell ios which image version it should load, depends on what device is currently in use.